# Is it possible to Clear all variables defined in a given cell?

Tags: notebooks, clear

Suppose I defined a number of variables in a cell, in the Notebook interface. I know the number of this cell (`In[296]`, for example). Is there a way to clear all the variables defined in this input (`In[296]`)?

Comment: In general no. How would you parse `x = ToExpression["y = 2"]` vs `x = Hold@ToExpression["y = 2"]`?

Comment: So it will be very complicated to parse it correctly, unless you narrow your case down to e.g. list of separate lines with simple assignments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much information has been given on the type of assignments so this solution just targets [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) assignments.

Collect the [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell.html) from its [`CellLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellLabel.html) .

```
{c} = Cells[CellLabel -> "In[296]:="]
```

Then collect assignment variables at all levels and [`ClearAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html) the variables.

```
ClearAll[#] & /@ 
  Cases[NotebookRead[c], HoldPattern[RowBox[{sym_, "=", _}]] :> sym, 
   Infinity];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Probably NotebookImport can help.